# Convert NHibernate IList to List in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, list, ilist

I have NHibernate IList. I want to convert to a List. Please help me.

### Here is my code

```
IList<Tag> list = Tag.GetAll();
```

I want to convert this to list

```
public class CategoryTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public CategoryTag()
    {

    }

    public List<CategoryTag> GetCategoryTagList()
    {
         IList<Tag> list = Tag.GetAll();

         // How do I return Tag as List?

        return tagList;
    }
}
```

### Update

I want to update my question since my question is not well explained.

Here is my code to pass it to jQuery UI Autocomplete:

```
[WebMethod]
    public IList<Tag> FetchTagList(string tag)
    {
        var ctag = new List<Tag>(Tag.GetAll())
            .Where(m => m.TagName.ToLower().StartsWith(tag.ToLower()));
        return ctag.ToList();
    }
```

I get following error:

Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[QuestionCenter.Domain.Tag, QuestionCenter.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Any solution to pass my IList to JSON will help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need a list?  Returning IList is actually the preferred approach as it not a specific implementation of the list data structure

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass it to JSON with webservice.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/aeff4155-ba84-488c-a400-90834f6c2c74/

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ:

```
return tagList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .ToList() extension method:

```
return list.ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the return type to Tag[] and use ToArray() instead of ToList(). IIRC, you cannot serialize an IList in a webmethod.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = Tag.GetAll()
                 .ConvertAll(tag => new CategoryTag{ Id = tag.Id, XXX = tag.YYY})
                 .ToList();
```

**Update**

Based on your comment to your answer I would use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) instead.

Comment: Like I said it's NHibernate IList. I get this error with your code:

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<QuestionCenter.Domain.Tag>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<QuestionCenter.Website.CategoryTag>' D:\MyFiles\QuestionCenter\QuestionCenter.Website\QuestionCenter.Website\CategoryTag.cs 23 21 QuestionCenter.Website

Comment: I'm getting this following error Cannot serialize member QuestionCenter.Domain.Tag.QuestionTags of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[QuestionCenter.Domain.QuestionTag, QuestionCenter.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

return Tag.GetAll().ToList() does not work for you?

Comment: Because it's NHibernate IList. I need to convert it to List.

Comment: no. `IList` is not something that nhibernate have invented. What you mean is that you need to convert a `Tag` list to a `CategoryTag` list which is your DTO.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is, pass NHibernate IList<Tag> to JSON using via Webservice. CategoryTag class is just a middle man to convert IList to List. If it's posible pass IList to JSON with Tag class, I wouldn't need CategoryTag class.

Comment: @ Mr. D: Well, you'll have to map Tag to CategoryTag. You can do left to right assignment yourself or use AutoMapper object-to-object mapper.